# What keyboard shortcut should be implemented for a search & replace dialog?

Tags: shortcut-keys, text-editor, usability

Some text editors use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> while others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -- some even know both. Should maybe the Find dialog double as Replace dialog, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> would be another option?

Is there user experience style guide on that? Cheers

Comment: You already found out that different editors use different shortcuts, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Good point ;) I wonder if there's a kind of style guide for Ubuntu/Gnome/Desktop environments that developers should adhere to ...

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6871/most-intuitive-keyboard-shortcut-for-search-replace-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in [WordPad](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts) and Microsoft [Office](https://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HP010370109.aspx).

[Gnome](http://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/input-keyboard.html.en#standard-shortcuts) recommends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

KDE recommends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> :-(

It looks like [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) & [LibreOffice](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> since their normal search can replace too.

See also [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts).

Therefore, it is a bug for any non-KDE app to use something other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for Replace, except when Replace is not separate than Find.